# EventBinding for dynamically added TextArea

Tags: jquery

Iam having some trouble with binding event listeners to dynamically created TextArea controls using Jquery.

Here is my scenario.

I need to make provide the ability to the end users for creating TextArea controls on hitting an add button. I also need to make use of Autosize functionality. I browsed the web and (for now) decided to make use of Jtextarea.js plugin (http://www.jscripts.info/jtextarea.php) for achieving autosize functionality. So far so good, I am able to dynamically create textareas on the fly but having difficulty on making them autosized.

Can I be provided with some info on how I can achieve this.?

Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jtextarea.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.textarea').jtextarea();
                $(document).on('', '.textarea', function (e) {
                    $('.textarea').jtextarea();
                });
            });

            function addBullet() {
                $('#myOrderedList').append('<li><textarea class="textarea"></textarea><a href="javascript:;" class="itemDelete">(x)</a></li>');
                // alert("button clicked");
            }

            $($(document)).on('click', '.itemDelete', function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                //alert("x clicked");
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            textarea {
                height: 20px;
                width: 300px;
            }

            #myOrderedList {
                list-style: decimal-leading-zero;
            }

            li textarea {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="myOrderedList">
            <li><textarea class="textarea"></textarea></li>
        </ul>
        <button onclick="addBullet()">Add</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vickel, this is the 1st time I am posting on stackoverflow. Can you pls let me know how I can post my html here. Thanks. I tried making use of code block but the html is getting stripped. thanks.

Comment: Okay, I will try changing the plugin to the one you suggested. I am a total newbie to jquery and henceforth struggling to make it work. Also, I am not seeing that the CSS classes are not in effect for the dynamically created text area. Please tell me where I am wrong or is this not the correct approach for doing so. In short, I want the dynamically added Textareas to be autosized and also they should take the css that I already specified for the default text box. Thanks much for your comments and support.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that your selected script has some problems (see the Comments and Questions part of the link you provided). I'd suggest for example: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/
their example works.

You also need to clean up (re-write) your java script code, for example you are initializing `jtextarea()` twice.